# AngularJs navbar parent view should be active when any child view are active

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router, navbar

I want to achieve that first view is based on some sub-views and main view is abstract - only redirect to first sub-view. I implementd two nav bars for navigation. One for navigation for normal views, and second to navigate only on home sub views. I wonder how to set up main navbar to be active on home when one of home sub-views are active.

Below code of top bar navbar. Home button should be active when any of sub views of home are active(home.a, home.b). At the moment Home is never active.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li> //here i can use home.a but when i will navigate to home.b it ll be inactive
    <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
    <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

sub views navbar works correct whenever i am on some sub views correct button is active

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="home.a">Wspolne</a></li>
  <li ui-sref-active="active"><a ui-sref="home.b">Moje</a></li>
</ul>
```

This route is close for soution main navbar is selected when sub-vievs active, but when i will change main view to contact then I cannot back to home cause it is abstract view:

```
.state('home', {
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
  controller: 'MainController',
  controllerAs: 'ctrl'
})
.state('home.a', {
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: 'app/main/a/a.html',
  controller: 'AController',
  controllerAs: 'ctrl'
})
.state('home.b', {
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: 'app/main/b/b.html',
  controller: 'BController',
  controllerAs: 'ctrl'
})
.state('contact', {
  url: '/contact',
  templateUrl: 'app/contact/contact.html',
  controller: 'ContactController',
  controllerAs: 'ctrl'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change active condition to refer to state object, and change ui-sref to href of child path:

```
<li ng-class="{active: ctrl.$state.includes('home')}"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
```

This is working bu it isnt elegant. Any better solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

hi maybe to late but try this ;)

```
<div ui-sref-active="{'active': 'admin.**'}">
  <a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="admin.roles">Roles</a>
</div>
```